# Can TV antenna be used as Radio Antenna?

Tags: antenna

I tried the Coax Cable that is used for our television - make its copper core have contact to the [antenna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHHOi.jpg) of my radio... but nothing happens, it doesn't improved the signal...

I also tried [this](https://i.imgur.com/2sUqScF.jpg), still nothing.

Comment: Why did you think it would work? Coax is simply a transmission line (a wire to transfer the signal from the aerial - which picks up the signal) to the receiver. **It isn't an aerial**. If you disconnected the aerial (at the aerial) from the coax for your TV would you expect that to work? If it did why would we need the aerial?

Comment: @JIm Dearden Well, actually, if you just disconnect the antenna and connect the coax center conductor to a radio, there's quite good chance that there will be signal at the radio receiver. If shield is connected instead of center conductor, the result is the famous long wire antenna. Sure, it's far from a real antenna, but in some cases might be better than included telescopic antenna.

Comment: @AndrejaKo even better if you attach a proper VHF aerial to the other end of the coax and use it as it was designed for . Any old bit of wire (and yes I have used a coat hanger) **can** be used as an aerial but it doesn't make it a good aerial.

Comment: Why do think that adding a bit to the length of an antenna should make it better?

Answer (score 1):

You have a radio that receives *medium wavelength* (AM broadcast), *short wavelength* (shortwave), as well as FM broadcast.
The span of frequencies covered is very wide. An optimum antenna for the bottom end of the AM broadcast band might be 130 metres long, while an optimum antenna for top-of-FM broadcast band might be 0.7 metres long. Although your telescoping antenna can have its length varied, it telescopes mostly to allow convenient storage while not in use. And it certainly cannot be extended to 130 m.
The short antenna provided is *far too short* for some of the available tuning range of your radio, so the manufacturer has likely included additional internal components to improve its efficiency. They expect that the radio antenna will be used "as is". For the lower frequencies, a ferrite-rod component mounted inside the radio provides much of the signal.
[image: ferrite rod loopstick antenna]
Your telescoping external antenna is likely coupled into this component to provide reasonable coverage (not optimum) of the entire span of receivable frequencies. Attaching external long antennas to the telescoping antenna likely disturbs the coupling, resulting in less-than-optimum signal power.
High performance radios have no internal antenna, and expect the user to provide signal power at a constant resistance (often 50 ohms) to a coaxial connector. Your "consumer" radio is not of this class, but it is more convenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

An FM radio antenna is about 0.75 metres long for a very good reason - its dimensions make it a quarter wave monopole and this maximizes the received radio signal amplitude for frequencies around 100 MHz. 100 MHz has a wavelength of 3 metres and one quarter of this is 0.75 metres. Adding or subtracting more length could make the signal received weaker but it sure won't improve it.

Comment: What about say 1/2 or 5/8 wavelength monopole antennas?

Comment: @AndrejaKo the 1/2 wavelength antenna will likely have an output impedance of circa 2000 ohms so the input circuits designed for a 1/4 wave monopole will probably significantly attenuate its signal because a 1/4 wave monopole is expected and it has an impedance of only 37 ohms. Similar story for a 5/8 antenna: http://www.aa5tb.com/efhw_13.gif